# Adding average column in pivot table to be used as avg. line in pivot chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table and chart that show data from an excel table. I would like to add a simple line to the chart that shows the avg. count for the column, but because it is a pivot table/chart I can't just add a line.

So my question is, Is there a way to add a "static entry in a pivot table and calculate the average outside of the table, or can I somehow come up with an AVG. number and add a third column with that avg?

Example Photo:
[image]

I would like to have the average of complaints be a third column that just has 1.5 for each user so that it will show up on the chart as another series so that I can change that series to a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you would do it using a pivottable but here is another workaround. Assuming your data is in the format below:

[image]

Put this formula in cell F9 to get the user count:

```
=COUNTA(H:H)-3
```

F10:

```
="I" & (F9+4)
```

F11:

```
="J" & (F9+4)
```

F12:

```
=INDIRECT(F10)
```

F13:

```
=INDIRECT(F11)
```

F14:

```
=F12/F9
```

F15:

```
=F13/F9
```

You will get the average in in cells F14 and F15.

Comment: Thanks for the responce VBA Programmer. I do need the data in the pivot table, but this is a great way to get the average.